# Image not appearing in Today Extension Widget

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-simulator

Really struggling with this problem:

The image (the checked tick) appears in the preview and has constraints etc but doesn't show up on the simulator widget.  Other elements on the storyboard show up ok but NOT the image

[image]

I believe I have set all my constraints correctly.  The image view has an outlet to the Today View Controller and no other code mention (haven't started coding its function yet until I can see it)

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Check the target membership of the Assets

[image]

Comment: Aaarg, I really don't understand why the debugger is not throwing - at least - a warning in this case...   :(

Answer (score 0):

Selected on Image Which added on your project Resource, show the file inspector, enable the target for the Image filename for which TodayExtenstion is created.

After that you can able to use the images inside widget too.

If you are using the Assets.xcassets Colors or Images make sure you select those target too for TodayExtenstion, So you can avoid the warnings.